# Replacing an if statement with a disjunction

Tags: java, grammar, boolean-logic, short-circuiting

Just for fun, I was trying to replace:

```
if (set1.add(x) == false)
{
    set2.add(x);
}
```

with:

```
set1.add(x) || set2.add(x);
```

However, Eclipse complains:

```
Syntax error on token "||", invalid AssignmentOperator
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
```

Could anybody shine some light onto these error messages? They don't make much sense to me.

Comment: As it says; it needs to be something like: `boolean temp = set1.add(x) || set2.add(x);`.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Well, what do you have on the left side of `set1.add(x) || set2.add(x)`?

Comment: How about `set1.add(x) ? false : set2.add(x)`?  (Haven't tried it, and the Java rules are obscure at times, so I'm not claiming it will work any better.)

Comment: because that is not a statement.

Comment: @barakmanos Nothing, `set1.add(x) || set2.add(x);` is the complete line.

Comment: @qqilihq Thanks, but now I get a warning about an unused variable :)

Comment: +1 for spotting this oddity. Incidentally, `bool foo(){return true;} bool bar(){return true;} int main(){ foo() || bar(); return 0;}` is valid C and C++. So it must be some oddity in JLS grammar or a compile bug.

Comment: @vefthym The question title makes the OP's intention perfectly clear IMHO.

Comment: This is an advanced-topic question: it's unlikely that, with 78k reputation, the OP is asking something simple. It interests me since, in C, an `expression-statement` is of the form `expression_opt;` and so the construct is valid C. But Eclipse / Java is disallowing it for some reason.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I've replaced if-statement tag with Grammar. You OK with that?

Comment: @Bathsheba It is difference between the C/C++ grammars and Java.  The JLS specifically calls it out;  in Java, not every expression can be used as a statement.  I've included citations in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21757543/1281433).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of answers far, but I agree with [Bohemian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21756452/1281433) that the most straightforward simplification (although it doesn't use `||`) is this:

```
if ( !set1.add(x) ) set2.add(x);
```

That doesn't explain the error message though. [Mustafa Genç comes closer on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21755051/1281433), but I think it's worthwhile to look at the language specification here.  `exp1 || exp2` is an expression, and the problem here is that you're trying to use it in a context where a statement is expected. According to [14.8. Expression Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8), some kinds of expressions can be used where statements are expected by attaching a semicolon:

> ### [14.8. Expression Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8)
>
> Certain kinds of expressions may be used as statements by following
>   them with semicolons.
>
> ```
> ExpressionStatement:
>     StatementExpression ;
>
> StatementExpression:
>     Assignment
>     PreIncrementExpression
>     PreDecrementExpression
>     PostIncrementExpression
>     PostDecrementExpression
>     MethodInvocation
>     ClassInstanceCreationExpression
> ```
>
> An expression statement is executed by evaluating the expression; if
>   the expression has a value, the value is discarded.

The reason that you can't do what you're trying to do, though, is that not every expression can be used as a statement.  However, it does discuss some ways to work around this. From the same section of the specification (emphasis added):

> *Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language allows only certain
>   forms of expressions to be used as expression statements. Note that
>   the Java programming language does not allow a "cast to `void`" - `void`
>   is not a type - so the traditional C trick of writing an expression
>   statement such as:*
>
> ```
> (void)... ;  // incorrect!
> ```
>
> *does not work. On the other hand, the Java
>   programming language allows all the most useful kinds of expressions
>   in expressions statements, and it does not require a method invocation
>   used as an expression statement to invoke a void method, so such a
>   trick is almost never needed. **If a trick is needed, either an
>   assignment statement (§15.26) or a local variable declaration
>   statement (§14.4) can be used instead.***

This approach is what the first snipped in [Reik Val's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21754970/1281433) is using:

```
boolean temp = set1.add(x) || set2.add(x);
```

Answer (score 7):

As @qqilihq said in the comments try to do

```
boolean temp = set1.add(x) || set2.add(x);
```

or more awkward:

```
if(set1.add(x) || set2.add(x));
```

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking for a solution fix, but is postulating why Java grammar doesn't allow the construct. Note that the equivalent syntax is valid in C and C++.

Answer (score 5):

According to documentation java statements which can end with a semicolon are:

```
Assignment expressions
Any use of ++ or --
Method invocations
Object creation expressions
```

What you've written is not a `statement` it's an `expression`. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html) you can find more about statements and expressions. So simple but worth to look.

Answer (score 1):

I would just:

```
if (!set1.add(x))
    set2.add(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
boolean temp = set1.add(x) || set2.add(x);
```

and any variation thereof is dangerous. You'll hardly ever know what happens there. Note that the right expression is NOT evaludated iff the first expression is `true`. That is, the attempt to add it to set2 will only be made if it was not yet contained in set1.

> EDIT: Now, reading the question again, it seems that this was exactly what you intended. So I think that the anser https://stackoverflow.com/a/21755051 by Mustafa Genç is the relevant here

Usually, you should write clearly what you want to do

```
boolean wasNotContainedInSet1 = set1.add(x);    
boolean wasNotContainedInSet2 = set2.add(x);    
boolean wasNotContainedInAnySet = 
    wasNotContainedInSet1 | wasNotContainedInSet2;
```

or

```
boolean wasNotContainedInSet1 = set1.add(x);    
if (!wasNotContainedInSet1) {
    set2.add(x);    
}
```

or whatever...

Comment: Not adding `x` to `set2` if it was already contained in `set1` is exactly what I want :)

Comment: @FredOverflow Yes, sorry, you might have seen the "EDIT" - I realized to late that this was your actual intention and that this was more or less an "academic" question. Mustafa Genç and Joshua Taylor explained quite that the actual problem was the fact that the the attempt with `set1.add(x) || set2.add(x)` was that this was not a statement.